# Returning and receiving map in callable Firebase functions

Tags: javascript, java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

is there a way to return a map from a firebase callable function to client using Android - Java? Basically just create a map inside a firebase function (using .js) and return it to the client android Java application. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Callable Cloud Functions can return [JSON types](https://json.org) only. From the documentation on [sending back the results:](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable?gen=2nd#sending_back_the_result):

> To send data back to the client, return data that can be JSON encoded.

So you'll have to encode the data for the map as JSON before returning it and then decode it back into a map in your Android code.